# How to do a case insensitive search in ed line editor

Tags: regex, bash, ed

I am trying to do a regex search with ed.

e.g.

Is there an expression that will match any case variation on the word "prop"

prop, PROP, Prop, etc. ?

I found the following additional references

[ed manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/ed.html)

which refers to

[Base Definitions volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001, Section 9.3, Basic Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html)

[GNU Basic Regular Expressions (grep, ed, sed)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/gnu.html)

Comment: Try `(?i)prop`. Or `[pP][rR][oO][Pp]`.

Comment: Thanks - [pP][rR][oO][Pp] works. I wasn't able to use (?i)prop - Maybe I used it wrong. I tried:    /(?i)prop     and also    /(?i)prop/   - neither works. Following your comment I am looking further into POSIX regex. Thanks

Comment: I am looking into ex - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_(text_editor) - it supports turning on\off search case sensitivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [*ed* regular expression syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/ed-regular-expression-syntax.html),  being a sort of a POSIX regular expression standard, does not seem to support case insensitive modifiers.

You may use bracket expressions containing both upper- and lowercase letter variants:

```
[Pp][Rr][Oo][Pp]
```

where `[Pp]` matches a `p` or `P`, etc.

If you plan to match `prop` as a whole word, you will need to use `\<` in front (it matches the beginning of a word) and a `\>` at the end of the expression (it matches the end of a word).